# Getting data from fragments with no variable attached to it

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-fragments

```
private void generateFragments() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWorkouts; i++) {
        ft.add(LinearLayoutID, new ExerciseFragment());
    }
    ft.commit();
}
```

The above code creates a dynamic number of fragments according to the value retrieved from a NumberPicker. This was the only way I could find to achieve the dynamic fragment creation I required, but the problem is I need to access the information later in my application, which would by fine if I hadn't used "new ExerciseFragment()".

- The question is, how can I get the information out of my ExerciseFragment's?

  - Each one contains 3 NumberPickers and one EditText.
  - Number of fragments can vary from 1 to 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWorkouts; i++) {
    ft.add(LinearLayoutID, new ExerciseFragment(), "TAG"+i);
}
```

Each of your fragments would have a unique TAG in the transaction manager and therefore you could retrieve them from this TAG with `findFragmentByTag`

[add()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29)

[findFragmentByTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something exactly like that, I appreciate the help.